# This site can’t be reached - Docker

Tags: asp.net, docker

I have created the `Containers / Apps`

[image]

But when I run it, I got this error message: This site can’t be reached. localhost unexpectedly closed the connection.
[image]

But when I run from Visual Studio, I can run it.

[image]

[image]

Extra troubleshooting steps is below
[image]

This is docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-focal AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-dotnet-configure-containers
RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApplication3/WebApplication3.csproj", "WebApplication3/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApplication3/WebApplication3.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApplication3"
RUN dotnet build "WebApplication3.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApplication3.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication3.dll"]
```

Comment: Can you show output of the CLI Command: "docker ps -a" and "docker network ls". This makes debugging much easier.

Comment: @BertC ok i have just added

Comment: You seem to have attached several images to this question, but not included any of the actual source code necessary to reproduce it.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Make sure to include the source code as text, not as images, and to include details about how you started the container.

Comment: ok i added the docker file

Comment: i got the same problem - the source code is the default generated code for a new project from VS 2022 web api project - no changes at all - works when run in the other scaffolded configurations but exact same error as this when the docker configuration is chosen

Comment: everything shows up in the docker ps command with ports mapped but browsing to the swagger or weatherforecast routes gives "This site can't be reached" for https://localhost:49157/weatherforecast (https from chrome) or http://localhost:49158/weatherforecast (http from firefox)

Answer (score 3):

By default, Swagger is only available when the app runs in development mode. Docker containers, by default, don't run in development mode.

Try accessing the API directly on http://localhost:49155/WeatherForecast

You can run the container in development mode by setting the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Development by adding the option `-e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` to your `docker run` command. Then Swagger should be available.

Comment: I tried http://localhost:49155/WeatherForecast but it still got error message. This page isn’t working